# How to inherit different types of models

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I have

```
public abstract class LogsCommonParser : LogSettingsViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<LogTableGridModel> ParseFoundLogs(object data)
        {
            Stream stream = CargoSrv.GetCargoSrv.GetFile(Logs.path);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

            IEnumerable<object> jsonObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<object>>(json);

            reader.Close();

            reader.Dispose();

            var collection = CookLogsForGrid(jsonObjects);
            return collection;
        }
        public abstract ObservableCollection<LogTableGridModel> CookLogsForGrid(IEnumerable<dynamic> data);
    }
```

And I want to

```
public class LogsDetailParser: LogsCommonParser
    {
        public override ObservableCollection<LogRowDropDownModel> CookLogsForGrid(IEnumerable<dynamic> data)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and

```
public abstract class LogsCoreParser:LogsCommonParser
    {
        private int _pageSize;

        public ObservableCollection<LogTableGridModel> FindLogsByCommand(string data)
        {

            var forServerModel = new FindLogsServerModel
            {
                Method = data,
                FileUId = InspectorRecordSearchingValue
            };

            var collection = ParseFoundLogs(Logs);
            return collection;
        }
    }
```

Problem in my model :LogRowDropDownModel. I can not inherit it from my base class.

I want to use different models in different inherited classes.
One model for main information and another for additional.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: The best way to do this would probably be to use generics. However, it would also require making the `ParseFoundLogs` generic too.

Comment: And how this should be probably looks like?

Comment: Need more information to know what you want to do